# readtable and invalid variable names

Tags: matlab

I have a script that converts a simulation data file that has variable names like force(1), velocity(2), etc.  I have a script that converts the data file to CSV file and up to Matlab 2016b, I was able to import that CSV file to Workspace as a table by using 'readtable'.  Readtable would issue a warning that says Matlab modifies those invalid variable names, but still import successfully by replacing the parentheses with underscores: a very minimum amount of modification.

Now with 2017b, readtable doesn't do what it used to do and the imported table variables have completely arbitrary names such as var1, var2, and such: a significant amount of modification.

How can I force readtable modify the variable names like it used to do?  Here's a snap shot of the CSV file and it's the "S_Out_DE10(1)" variable name causing the havoc.

[image]

I can't use the GUI because I actually bring in multiple files and create table variables in a batch.

I open the CSV file, Cntr+S or Save button, say 'OK' when asked to keep the same format, and 'No' to the same question when closing the file; all without touching a single cell.

Here is a text format of some of the data:

```
    TIME    S_Out_DE10(1)   Vph x_ehsv  mA_ehsv
0   0   0   0   0
0.001   0   0   0   0
0.002   0   0   0   0
0.003   0   0   0   0
0.004   0   0   0   0
```

Now, the funny thing is if you copy/past the above and "save" it into a CSV file, that "saving" again makes it work.

Comment: @Adriaan, how do I attach a file?  I don't see a button for it in the editor.  One bizarre thing I discovered just now is that if I open the CSV file and save it without touching anything, readtable works like described above: replacing a parenthesis with an underscore.  Does that give you a clue?  If not, please teach me how to upload a file.

Comment: @Adriaan, done as requested.

Comment: Saving is done in what kind of spreadsheet editor? If you're on Windows and using Excel, you might want to look into `xlsread` instead.

Comment: yes, Windows and Excel.  Data file can have any number of columns (variables) and any number of rows (data points).  I prefer readtable because I also use "table2struct".  Here's the scheme: tbl = readtable(file_csv);strct = table2struct(tbl,'ToScalar',true);save(file_name,'-struct','strct'); Very fast and efficient.

Comment: @Adriaan, I got it to work with some more lines of code.  I convert the CSV file to XLS.  Then, reading the XLS file does that modification.  Thank you.  Do you mind repeating the above in your answer so that I can give you the credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a CSV file with headers (for which it is not designed), you can use [`xlsread`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) to directly read your Excel files instead.

Comment: @Andriaan, thank you.  If you have any clue as to why saving the CSV file works with "readtable" in 2017b, please let me know.